# Digging a polygon according to another with libgdx

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, libgdx, csg

I actually develop a 3D application on Android, and i manipulate 3D object.

I want to dig a polygon according to another polygon form such as a cube or a cylinder.
In the following image you can imagine I have two superimposed polygons, a cylinder and a  rectangular cuboid.
If I get the intersection of these two polygons and I calculate the inverse (included in the rectangular cuboid) I get a new polygon with a hole in the shape of the cylinder like in this picture.

I don't know how to achieve this with libGDX, I know the Intersector class, but I do not know how to retrieve the reverse of an intersection between two polygons.

[image]

Comment: So [constructive solid geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry)?  Or just the 2D case of [Boolean operations on polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons)?

Comment: Yes, that's it, but if there is another way to achieve that is not CSG, I'm interested also.